# What is the most efficient way to parse JSON fields in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Imagine the table `my_table` with the rows:

| COLUMN_1 | COLUMN_2 | COLUMN_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "test_1212" | {date: 1646240118, name: "John", age: null} | "test_2311" |
| "test_998" | null | "test_26351" |
| "test_56551" | {age: 20} | "test_3323" |

Here, `COLUMN_2` is of `JSON` or `null`. The JSON fields could have a value, be `null`, or not exist.

I'm writing a query that unpacks the JSON field **if it exists and has a value**. Below is what I have and I'm curious if having multiple case statement could affect the performance and if there is a better way to do this?

Note that above is just an example and the actual JSON could have up to 10 fields. Optionally I can unpack the JSON on the code side instead of SQL if it improves the performance.

```sql
SELECT COLUMN_1,
       CASE WHEN json_value(COLUMN_2, '$.date') IS NOT NULL THEN json_value(COLUMN_2, '$.date')
           END AS date,
       CASE WHEN json_value(COLUMN_2, '$.name') IS NOT NULL THEN json_value(COLUMN_2, '$.name')
           END AS name,
       CASE WHEN json_value(COLUMN_2, '$.age') IS NOT NULL THEN json_value(COLUMN_2, '$.age')
           END AS age,
       COLUMN_3
FROM my_table
```

I am using Oracle version 12.2.0.1.0 (12c).

Comment: If the value is not null, then `case` will return that value. If it is null, then `case` will return null. What is the purpose of `case` here?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is unpack the field if it exists (e.g. `date`) and has a value. Ideally if the field doesn't exist or if the field is null, I do not want to unpack it.

Comment: So what do you want as an output if the value doesn't exist?

Comment: @astentx If the value doesn't exist, let's say `date` in this case, so the JSON looks like `{name: "Joh", age: 22}`. Right now I have `date` evaluate to `null` so the result is  `null, "John", 22` but what I want is `"John", 22`.

Comment: Please add to your question what version of oracle you're on

Comment: @KoenLostrie Just did. 12.2.0.1.0 (12c).

Comment: Function like json_table can also be used in this scenario.

Comment: Oracle is RDBMS. In relational DBMS result set is like a table with rows and columns. Obviously, a column is present or not in the table, not in the individual row

Comment: @astenix - a specific key may be missing in a JSON object. The OP is talking about missing keys in the JSON, not missing columns in the table. His question makes perfect sense.

Comment: @Dante - to check for existence of a key, you should use JSON_EXISTS. That makes some sense (checking for existence of a key is much faster than retrieving the value); the way you are doing it you are not saving any time. But, if you need to retrieve all keys and values, the fasterst way is JSON_TABLE; do all in one pass. Happily, Oracle **optimizes** your version of the query to a single invocation of JSON_TABLE anyway; your solution is (after optimization) equivalent to the two answers you received.

Comment: @mathguy But in the above comment they say: *the result is  `null, "John", 22` but what I want is `"John", 22`* This is my point of confusion. And I really do not understand the reason to check the key existence before the value extraction, because absent key will evaluate to `null`, exactly the same as the `case` expression will do, so I've requested a clarification of this part of code. Can you please suggest the reason to check, if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `JSON_TABLE` with `OUTER APPLY`:

```sql
SELECT column_1,
       column_3,
       j.*
FROM   my_table m
       OUTER APPLY JSON_TABLE(
         m.column_2,
         '$'
         COLUMNS (
           dt   NUMBER       PATH '$.date',
           name VARCHAR2(50) PATH '$.name',
           age  NUMBER       PATH '$.age'
         )
       ) j;
```

Or, if you prefer to use an ANSI standard `LATERAL` join rather than the proprietary `OUTER APPLY` then:

```sql
SELECT column_1,
       column_3,
       j.*
FROM   my_table m
       LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT *
         FROM   JSON_TABLE(
                  m.column_2,
                  '$'
                  COLUMNS (
                    dt   NUMBER       PATH '$.date',
                    name VARCHAR2(50) PATH '$.name',
                    age  NUMBER       PATH '$.age'
                  )
                )
       ) j
       ON (1 = 1);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table (COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2, COLUMN_3) AS
SELECT 'test_1212',  '{date: 1646240118, name: "John", age: null}', 'test_2311' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'test_998',   null, 'test_26351' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'test_56551', '{age: 20}', 'test_3323' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> | COLUMN_1 | COLUMN_3 | DT | NAME | AGE |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | test_1212 | test_2311 | 1646240118 | John | *null* |
> | test_998 | test_26351 | *null* | *null* | *null* |
> | test_56551 | test_3323 | *null* | *null* | 20 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=84ee1c0fa69461a57f75e46f06e81b99)*

Comment: I'm curious what's the best way to convert one of the JSON fields if the JSON field exists? For example `dt` in `dt   NUMBER       PATH '$.date'` to s string if `dt` field is present in the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON_TABLE to parse field values -

```
SQL> with data_cte (col1, col2, col3) as
  2  (
  3  select 'COLUMN_1',json_object('date' value 1646240118, 'name' value 'John', 'age' value null), 'COLUMN_3' from dual union all
  4  select 'COLUMN_1', null, 'COLUMN_3'  from dual union all
  5  select 'COLUMN_1', json_object('date' value null, 'name' value 'Tom', 'age' value 20), 'COLUMN_3' from dual
  6  )select col1, t.*, col3 from data_cte, json_table(col2,'$'
  7  columns (
  8  date_1 varchar2(10) path '$.date',
  9  name varchar2(21) path '$.name',
 10  age varchar2(10) path '$.age')
 11  ) t;

COL1     DATE_1       NAME       AGE        COL3
-------- ------------ ---------- ---------- --------
COLUMN_1 1646240118   John                  COLUMN_3
COLUMN_1              Tom        20         COLUMN_3
```